# Codewars keeps timing out - is my code really that inefficient?

Tags: python

I have been working on this binary bit counter for about an hour and was hoping someone could help me out. Codewars keeps timing out when I submit the kata. Is my code really that slow? I wanted to see if I could receive help before looking at the solutions.

```
import math
def count_bits(n):
    bits = 0
    x = True
    while x == True:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n / 2
        elif n % 2 != 0:
            bits += 1
            n = math.floor(n / 2)
        if n == 1 or n == 2:
            bits += 1
            x = False
    print(bits)
```

Comment: Have you tried `count_bits(0)` or `count_bits(1)`? Maybe these are part of the test set.

Comment: I tried your code in codewars also , I  don't get timeouts,

Comment: `n //= 2` will do an integer divide in both paths.

Comment: It is inefficient, though. You divide `n` by two three different times, when you only need to do so once. `n, r = divmod(n, 2); bits += r`.

Comment: Neither 1 nor 2 are special cases, though. You can divide both by 2 and get the appropriate value to add to `bits`. The real base case is `n == 0`.

Comment: Linking to the problem is a good idea.